# how to make maintain scroll position smooth

Tags: asp.net

I am using the `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback` feature in asp.net so the when the page posts back the page looks like it stayed in the same position. However when the page posts back it is very noticeable. The page loads at the top and then jumps down to the place that it was before. Is there a way to smooth this out so that when the page loads it loads to the previous position?

Comment: Have you considered eliminating postbacks entirely and using AJAX instead, so that the page is never really unloaded?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own function to make the scrolling to the previous position smooth. Normally the Y-position is stored in the hidden field `__SCROLLPOSITIONY`. But when you disable `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback`, this form field will also disappear.

So create a `HiddenField` of your own and store the position there. Then after a PostBack you can read that value and scroll to it.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>").val()
        });
    });

    $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
        $("#<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>").val(e.pageY)
    });
</script>
```

I've tested this snippet only quickly, maybe it needs some more tweaking.